# Fix misaligned rows after converting PDF to text tm package

Tags: r, dataframe, tm

Using the tm package for R, I have converted a PDF table into text.  My goal is turn the PDF table into a data frame.  The original table in the PDF file has the structure:

```
1. [EMPTY] , V1 , V2 , V3
2. 01-01-2015 , 1.23 , 3.45 , 5.67 
3. 02-01-2015 , 8.9 , 1.23 , 4.56
```

Where the first column is a date but has no column name and the columns are otherwise delimited by the comma. The tm package has incorrectly converted the table to text in such a way that the date column has been incorrectly shifted upward:

```
1. 01-01-2015  ,   V1   ,  V2   ,  V3 
2. 02-01-2015 ,  1.23 ,  3.45 ,  5.67
3. 03-01-2015 ,  8.90  , 1.23  , 4.56
```

Such that the dates no longer correspond to the correct variable values V1, V2, etc.

I need to shift the first column down to realign the date and values correctly without shifting the other columns.  I'm open to doing this either using tm when I originally convert PDF to text, or after I've turned the text into a data frame.  I tried to pursue the latter strategy using data.table and other tools but have not had success.

Can anyone suggest any strategy for shifting the values of a single column without shifting the other column values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix this in several steps after you turned the PDF in a dataframe. In base R:

```
# set column names
names(mydf) <- c("date", as.character(unlist(mydf[1, 2:4])))

# shift the date column with one row downward
mydf$date <- lag(mydf$date, 1)

# delete the unnecessary first row
mydf <- mydf[-1,]

# set the column classes in the correct format
mydf$date <- as.Date(mydf$date, format="%d-%m-%Y")
mydf[,c(2:4)] <- lapply(mydf[,c(2:4)], function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))
```

With the *data.table* package:

```
names(mydf) <- c("date", as.character(unlist(mydf[1, 2:4])))

library(data.table)
mydf <- setDT(mydf)[, date := shift(date, 1)][-1]

mydf[, date := as.Date(date, format="%d-%m-%Y")
     ][, c("V1","V2","V3") := lapply(.SD, function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x))), .SDcols = c("V1","V2","V3")]
```

---

Used example data:

```
mydf <- read.table(text="
    01-01-2015  V1  V2  V3
    02-01-2015  1.23  3.45  5.67
    03-01-2015  8.90  1.23  4.56
", header=FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer.  Both suggestions work so I'm accepting this answer for its thoroughness.